# SQL Delete statement taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, query-performance

I have the below SQL delete statement. This is supposed to delete around 20000 records and its taking more than 12 minutes to execute. Here I am using the row number statement to fetch duplicates based on some criteria.
Any idea to modify the script to perform it better. Thanks in advance.

```
delete from @TempTable where id in(
        select  id
        from 
        (select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  Dep,  NrInvoiceLine, OfficeId, pol,  pod,  PreCarr, WarehouseId, DestinationPrecarr,
         DestinationWarehouseId, PortTerminalId, Product, isnull(description, ''), ScaleCalcuationId, isnull(scalefrom, 0), isnull(scaleto, 0),  
         CurrencyCode, Base, ShippingLineID, ContainerId, AgentId order by type) Record, a.id
        from  @TempTable a where cast(Date as smalldatetime) = '2078-12-31 00:00:00' and IsDeleted = 0 and 
        (RO = 1 or RO=2) and (PP = 0 or PP = 2) 
        )as b   
        where b.Record !=1 )
```

Comment: Can you add the explain plan of the select?

Comment: How many records are in this table variable `@TempTable`? If you're deleting 20K, I have to assume it has at least 20001 and table variables perform very poorly at that scale. Can you make it a **true** temp table (prefixed with `#`), maybe even index it?

Comment: Here I am fetching the duplicate records using the partition by statement based on the conditions that are mentioned in the where clause and then I am trying to delete those duplicates. Actually there is only one duplicate entry. but to delete that record from a total of 20k records, it is taking more than 12 minutes to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#temp` table instead of table variable and create the following index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_temp
  ON #temptable (Date, IsDeleted, RO, PP)
  include (id, Dep, NrInvoiceLine, OfficeId, pol, pod, PreCarr, WarehouseId, DestinationPrecarr, DestinationWarehouseId, PortTerminalId, Product, description, ScaleCalcuationId, scalefrom, scaleto, CurrencyCode, Base, ShippingLineID, ContainerId, AgentId);
```

and try changing the query like this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY Dep, NrInvoiceLine, OfficeId, pol, pod, PreCarr, WarehouseId, DestinationPrecarr, DestinationWarehouseId, PortTerminalId, Product, Isnull(description, ''), ScaleCalcuationId, Isnull(scalefrom, 0), Isnull(scaleto, 0), CurrencyCode, Base, ShippingLineID, ContainerId, AgentId
                    ORDER BY type) Record,
                a.id
         FROM   #temptable a
         WHERE  Date >= '2078-12-31 00:00:00'
                AND Date < Dateadd(dd, 1, '2078-12-31 00:00:00')
                AND IsDeleted = 0
                AND ( RO = 1
                       OR RO = 2 )
                AND ( PP = 0
                       OR PP = 2 ))
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  Record > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to break the query down in to smaller chunks. That’s a whopping great partition you’re performing.

Is there a simpler way of achieving the output you want? Do you need to delete from this table or can you create another with only the rows you want allowing you to then drop the table containing rows you’re not interested in? Same result different approach.

It may be worth also noting creating tables will mostly perform better than inserting and deleting rows.

Edit: I can see you’re trying to mitigate a duplicate that’s been returned. 99% of the time this is a means to clean up bad coding. Find out why the duplicate is introduced and take the relevant steps needed to properly fix the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the main cause of the poor performance is because table variables don't get accurate row estimates unless you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. So you are probably getting a plan based on estimates that the table variable contains much fewer rows than it actually does.

It is also unnecessary to have a subquery here.

You should find this executes much faster.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY Dep, NrInvoiceLine, OfficeId, pol, pod, PreCarr, WarehouseId, DestinationPrecarr, DestinationWarehouseId, PortTerminalId, Product, isnull(description, ''), ScaleCalcuationId, isnull(scalefrom, 0), isnull(scaleto, 0), CurrencyCode, Base, ShippingLineID, ContainerId, AgentId ORDER BY type) Record,
                a.id
         FROM   @TempTable a
         WHERE  cast(Date AS SMALLDATETIME) = '2078-12-31 00:00:00'
                AND IsDeleted = 0
                AND ( RO IN ( 1, 2 ) )
                AND ( PP IN ( 0, 2 ) ))
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE  Record > 1 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```